# MySQL/MariaDB - Setting global variable "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2" doesn't affect speed

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

I have set global variable of innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 2 but when I run command `ab.exe -n 200 -c 200 -s 9999 http://127.0.0.1/index.php` there is no difference in speed before and after that.

When the value of the variable is 1
[image: When the value of the variable is 1]

When the value of the variable is 2
[image: When the value of the variable is 2]

The query inside the file is written in php/laravel:

```
$status = ['enable', 'disable'];
try {
    \DB::beginTransaction();

    for($p = 1; $p <= 1000; $p++) {
        $price = mt_rand(1000, 5000);
        CarPrice::create([
            'car_id' => $p,
            'amount' => $price,
            'status' => $status[rand(0, 1)],
        ]);
    }

    \DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    \DB::rollback();
    die('Err!');
}
```

- Each time I modify `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`, I restart the Apache and MariaDB.
- Windows 10
- Ram: 8
- CPU: Pentium 3.3GHz
- Hard: HDD (Not SSD)

Comment: You have not asked a question about any specific code. You appear to be requesting a PHP script, but there's no way we can guess what's in that script. You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BillKarwin Edited with the code details.

Comment: Well, the program is somewhat faster in the second case. Why do you expect a radical change in commit speed after changing a single mariadb setting?

Comment: Because I thought by using that variable it will use ram instead of disk, so it would get 50 instead of 131 !!! @Shadow

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`? InnoDB will always use disk for the redo log, that's important to make sure transactions are durable.

Comment: When you set the value of that variable to 2, transactions still write to the log on every commit, but they allow the file system buffering to [cache the write temporarily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/flushing-system-buffered-i-o-data-to-disk). But even with the variable set to 2, InnoDB will still force a filesync every 1 second, so the buffered writes are pushed through to the physical disk pretty frequently.

Comment: Your benchmark appears to only run 200 transactions, if I understand the arguments to `ab` correctly. That's probably not enough load to show any detectable difference between the different innodb log flush settings. Benchmarks often have to be run for _hours_ to show a difference. I run mine for 8 hours, and yes, I do see significant changes in results over the hours. I don't use Windows though, so I don't know what your experience will be.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to `COMMIT` more than 100 transactions per second to see any difference.  That's with HDD; if you have SDD, it might be 1000.

Are you doing the following?

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT
INSERT
...
INSERT   -- 1000 1-row inserts in a single connection?
COMMIT;  -- This is where that setting makes a difference.
```

The `COMMIT` is such a tiny percentage of the total that it will be hard to measure.

The real speed up is to do this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT ... VALUES
    ( row ),
    ( row ),
    ...
    ( row );  -- one 1000-row insert?
COMMIT;  -- This is where that setting makes a difference.
```

That will, however, require changes to your app code.

Potential issue:  Do you need to grab `Last_insert_id()` for each row?

PS:  This would show off the diff with `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`; it will be much slower:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT
COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT
COMMIT;
...       -- 1000 1-row inserts in a single connection
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT 
COMMIT;  -- after each row inserted!
```